# Determine for what value(s) of m that the equation $ |2x-1| = mx+1$ has exactly one solution only.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

> Determine for what value(s) of m that the equation $|2x-1| = mx+1$ has exactly one solution only.

I don't really understand the steps I should undertake in solving this problem!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Sketch $y=|2x-1|$ and $y=mx+1$ for various values of $m$  to see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CASE $\bf1$:**$\ \ x>1/2$
$2x-1=mx+1$
$x=2/(2-m)$
So, $x=2/(2-m)$ AND $x>1/2$
$\Rightarrow 2/(2-m)>1/2$
$\Rightarrow m>-2, m\neq2$
$\Rightarrow m\in(-2,\infty)\sim2$

---

**CASE $\bf2$:** $\ \ x\leq1/2$
$1-2x=mx+1$
$(m+2)x=0$
$\Rightarrow m\neq-2,x=0 \cap x\leq1/2\qquad$ OR $\qquad m=-2,x\in R \cap x\leq1/2$
$\Rightarrow m\neq-2,x=0$ OR $m=-2,x\leq1/2$
Since we are interested in only $1$ solution so, $m\neq-2,x=0$

---

Now, our final answer is CASE $1$ $\cup$ CASE $2$
Since we are interested in only $1$ solution so we need $m$ s.t. it satisfies CASE $1$ or CASE $2$ but not both.
This can be done by excluding all the values of $m$ s.t. CASE $1$ is satisfied.
So, $(m\neq-2)-(m\in(-2,\infty)\sim2)$
$\Rightarrow m\in(-\infty,-2)$

---

Thus, for $m\in(-\infty,-2)$, we have only $1$ solution, $x=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! :)

Comment: You are very good at explaining!

Comment: @Angel_GrapeJuice I'm glad you liked it. Kindly note that I have made an edit as there should have been a union sign instead of intersection between CASE 1 and CASE 2.